# Cannot access object fields using lodash: Error cannot access objects element

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
export default {
  configuration:
  {
    site: {
      control:[
        api: {
          'list': '/api/v1/config/sites',
          'post': '/api/v1/config/sites/',
          'patch': '/api/v1/config/sites/',
          'delete': '/api/v1/config/sites/'
        }
      ],
    },
}
```

I am trying to access it by `_.get(configuration, ['site','control','api','list'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that your `configuration` structure is wrong, exactly in `control:[api: {...}]` the array doesn't support key/value structure like a literal object, so you should wrap that item by `{}` like `control:[{api: {...}}]` and access it like :

```
   _.get(configuration, ['site', 'control', '0', 'api', 'list'])
```

or transform your `control` value to an object like : `control:{api: {...}}`

the full example by wrapping `api` key  by `{}`

```js
let configuration = {
  site: {
    control: [{
      api: {
        'list': '/api/v1/config/sites',
        'post': '/api/v1/config/sites/',
        'patch': '/api/v1/config/sites/',
        'delete': '/api/v1/config/sites/'
      }
    }],
  }
}
var dumb = _.get(configuration, ['site','control','0','api','list'])

document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = dumb
console.log(_.get(configuration, ['site', 'control', '0', 'api', 'list']))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<p id="key"></p>
```

Comment: still i am facing the issue to display it in p tag. Could you help me with the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/thanseeh/2en7km3x/10/

Comment: do like i did in my answer use `innerHTML` instead of value like `document.getElementById("key").innerHTML=dumb` and don't use export default check this https://jsfiddle.net/ynkja2Lw/

Answer (score 2):

`control` is an array, so you can't access `control.api` without first specifying which index in the array you want. Rather, you need to do:

```
_.get(configuration, ['site','control', '0', 'api','list'])
```

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle for this please? ^^